# SVN Bi-Directional sync using svnsync

Tags: svn, version-control, synchronization, bidirectional

At the moment we have two development teams.  One of them is in a different country.  The master svn server is in location A.  The development team in location A has access to this server and creates branches from trunk and does their development.  The team in location B works off of the same trunk but does not have access to the master svn server.

Location B needs to have the latest trunk in order to create their branches.  They do not need to have write to trunk.

What I am looking to do is have only trunk synced from location A to location B.  But from location B have only their branches synced to location A.

I also want to keep syncing all location A to a disaster recovery site.

The recommendations I have read state that for the mirrored svn server, nothing but the svnsync tool should write to this server.  But I would assume that is referring to both servers writing to the same branch/trunk.  If that does not happen, is there still a danger?  Can the svnsync tool accomplish what I am looking to do?

Thanks

Comment: Found this article:  http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/39525/0/page/3  and we are going to set it up this way.  I will respond once we are done.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is not designed to support your workflow, since it can't cope with situations where different changes does have the same revision number. You can

1. place at both sites a read-only mirror of the other side
2. migrate to a VCS which is designed to support your situation (like Mercurial or git).

Answer (score 1):

> If that does not happen, is there still a danger?

Yes

> Can the svnsync tool accomplish what I am looking to do?

No

You must to exchange dumps in order to get bi-directional sync without headache and broken repos, but: moving to DVCS (Mercurial for SVN-background recommended, not Git) will be more natural way with *slightly* changed workflow